# Padding and packing in structures

Tags: c, performance

I know how structure padding works and also the necessity of padding dummy bytes of data. Padding increases the h/w performance by reducing the number of cycles to get same data.
On the other hand packing allows us to put the data next to each other and hence the CPU will(may) have to use multiple cycles to fetch entire data completely.
So what is the necessity of packing although it is reducing the performance.
Please suggest some situations where packing is necessary.
I am assuming the word length in h/w to be of 4bytes.

Thanks&Regards
Amit Kumar

Answer (score 2):

It is often a tradeoff between space/memory and CPU time. I use struct packing often in embedded code to reduce size, well aware that it costs some extra masking-instructions to use.

It may also be useful for data serialization/de-serialization where you can see the data structure more explicitly (declaratively?) if it is defined in terms of a packed struct.
This is however often a debatable position to take, as `memcpy`-ing directly between buffers and data structures is considered bad practice by many.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "packing" you mean removing the padding, using a non-standard pragma or attribute (such as Gcc's `__attribute__((packed))`). There are two main reasons you might do this:

1. Reduce memory allocation. If you will be allocating a large number of objects, the extra allocation due to the padding may be significant.
2. To make the in-memory layout reflect the layout on-disk (when dealing with particular file formats for example) or in a particular protocol. This may allow reading and writing the structure object directly, rather than having to deal separately with each field. (Byte order within individual fields may still be a concern).

In general, the practice is not portable and you should avoid it unless you have a very good reason.

In many cases it is possible to reduce the padding required by re-organizing your data structure: put the largest members first, and then place following members in decreasing order of size.

Comment: Nice  but `packing` is usually referred grouping objects as in case of structure. I didn't quite understand what op meant by it..

Comment: Thanks for your response.